# Change Magento Cart to UK shipping fields

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9, shopping-cart, cart

Hoping this is really simple but nothing seems that simple in Magento...But at the moment my cart says Country, State/Province, Zip.

BUT it's a UK shop, so how do I change these to the relevant county/postcode inputs?

I've changed everything I can possibly find to UK and I cant seem to make this show county and Postcode?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2):

Go and download the en_GB langauge pack from here: https://github.com/ecommerceheroes/magento_GB_LP and drop the contents in the following location;

app/locale/en_GB/

Then from admin, go to;

```
System > Configuration
```

(top menu).  Then from the left menu, go to;

```
General > General
```

In the central content, find the 'locale options' box and set your locale to: "English (United Kingdom)".  Flush your caches.  That will change the values on the frontend.

For extra bonus points, you can also get the admin interface in Queens English (clearly the best ;) ).  Open the file;

```
app/etc/config.xml
```

Search for the

```
<general>....
```

block and change the

```
<code>....
```

bit so it looks like this;

```
<code>en_GB</code>
```

Now you can stop reading 'catalog' and cursing the misuse of language ;)